# Deployment Error for all Objects : "Cannot create a new component with the namespace <objectname>"

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment

I am trying to deploy few files to a Salesforce Sandbox org from my Bitbucket repository master branch via Bitbucket pipeline for the first time. But getting a specific error for all the objects meta.xml files. What might be the reason ?

> Error: Cannot create a new component with the namespace 'objectname'. Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be
>   created through the API deployment

[image: Error]

Edit : I believe it has something to do with how object files are stored. I have recently shifted to VS Code and the object files in the source code I retrieved using package.xml is different compared to the earlier extracted files using Sublime/Atom.

[image: VS Code Extract]

Can this be the reason ? Is there a way I can retrieve the package in the traditional metadata format.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy appexhange package apps?

Comment: No. There are no appexchange package apps.

Comment: We'd have to see one of those metadata files to know more, but probably some errant `__` in the metadata's fullName attribute.

Comment: Added the metadata files.

Comment: @Brav Did you get any solution to this problem?